# Why is React EventListener not working in Netlify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dom-events, netlify

I am using HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I have an EventListener so a new quote is generated whenever I press the space button. This works on my localhost, but not on Netlify. How can I fix this?

```
window.addEventListener(`keydown`, function(event) {
    if (event.defaultPrevented) {
      return;
    }
    if (event.code === "Space"){
        fetch("http://api.quotable.io/random").then(response => response.json()).then(result => {
            quoteText.innerText = result.content;
            authorName.innerText = result.author;
        });
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}, true);
```

Comment: Share screenshot of you network tab. Some issue with the API call probably.

Comment: maybe replace the link with `https://api.quotable.io/random` as Netlify might be somehow blocking the insecure connection?

Comment: @TadeoHepperle wow thank you so much!!!!! i deployed it again and it worked!!!!! i hope you have a great day <33